# Deriving network modularity

Tags: graph-theory, network

My question is *exactly* what was [asked here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328747/modularity-in-a-graph-derivation-of-modularity-score):

Specifically:

> Given [this definition of $Q$] we proceed by writing $s$ as a linear combination of the normalised eigenvectors $u_i$ of $B$ so that $s = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i u_i$ with $a_i = u_i^T\cdot s$.

It's not clear to my why the membership vector $s$ (which can contain only 1 and -1) can be written like this.

The poster never came back to write up the solution, and I do not have the 50 reputation required to comment on Math Overflow, so I can't ask them for the solution.

The paper in question can be found [here](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/103/23/8577.full.pdf)

Comment: Hey -- I wrote a more elaborate answer to this [in my post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/356178/138750).

Comment: Excellent! It's getting late so i'll be reading in the morning. I'll have to comment here as I am unable to make comments on MathOverflow due to being under the reputation limit.

Comment: no prob, if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: @ngmir sorry for the late response. I've read your answer and proofs (as well as the ones you linked). Exactly what I was missing. To answer your question of why I was reading the paper: it is for a university course in which there is an emphasis on networks. We will be implementing a modularity algorithm and were given the paper as a starting point.

Comment: very glad this helped you :) I was exactly in the same spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear algebra thing.  The matrix B (called the modularity matrix in the paper of interest from the linked question) is real symmetric, and a property of real symmetric matrices is that their eigenvectors form an orthonormal basis.  The formula you ask about is just decomposing $s $ as a linear combination of these eigen-basis vectors.

Comment: I'm reading up on the properties of real symmetric matrices now. 

I'm still a bit lost on why a vector ($s$) can be expressed as a linear combinations of orthogonal eigenvectors of a different matrix ($B$).

The form it's written in looks suspeciously similar to the diagonalization example given here, except ours involves a dot product and vectors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices

Comment: @daviegravee Look at the second formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis#Basic_formula